# Youtube don't like some videos

Tags: video, ffmpeg, youtube, media-info

Well. I have a lot of videos in my server and I'm trying to upload to Youtube.
All videos were recorded using openeya, which uses ffmpeg to record.

My problem is, some videos are uploaded and other not.

So, to illustrate the problem I have `video A` and `video B`. Both videos were recorded in sequence, ends A and start B (pause of 20 minutes between them).

`video A` was upload successfully, `video B` not.

Using the `mediainfo` I get this info about `video A` Look:

```
General
Complete name                            : openeya.mp4
Format                                   : MPEG-4
Format profile                           : Base Media
Codec ID                                 : isom
File size                                : 78.2 MiB
Duration                                 : 41mn 57s
Overall bit rate                         : 261 Kbps
Encoded date                             : UTC 1904-01-01 00:00:00
Tagged date                              : UTC 1904-01-01 00:00:00
Writing application                      : Lavf56.25.101
Video
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : High@L1.2
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
Format settings, ReFrames                : 4 frames
Codec ID                                 : avc1
Codec ID/Info                            : Advanced Video Coding
Duration                                 : 41mn 57s
Bit rate                                 : 200 Kbps
Width                                    : 320 pixels
Height                                   : 240 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 4:3
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 10.000 fps
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.260
Stream size                              : 60.3 MiB (77%)
Writing library                          : x264 core 142 r2389 956c8d8
Encoding settings                        : cabac=1 / ref=3 / deblock=1:0:0 / analyse=0x3:0x113 / me=hex / subme=7 / psy=1 / psy_rd=1.00:0.00 / mixed_ref=1 / me_range=16 / chroma_me=1 / trellis=1 / 8x8dct=1 / cqm=0 / deadzone=21,11 / fast_pskip=1 / chroma_qp_offset=-2 / threads=6 / lookahead_threads=1 / sliced_threads=0 / nr=0 / decimate=1 / interlaced=0 / bluray_compat=0 / constrained_intra=0 / bframes=3 / b_pyramid=2 / b_adapt=1 / b_bias=0 / direct=1 / weightb=1 / open_gop=0 / weightp=2 / keyint=250 / keyint_min=10 / scenecut=40 / intra_refresh=0 / rc_lookahead=40 / rc=abr / mbtree=1 / bitrate=200 / ratetol=1.0 / qcomp=0.60 / qpmin=0 / qpmax=69 / qpstep=4 / ip_ratio=1.40 / aq=1:1.00
Encoded date                             : UTC 1904-01-01 00:00:00
Tagged date                              : UTC 1904-01-01 00:00:00
Audio
ID                                       : 2
Format                                   : AAC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Audio Codec
Format profile                           : LC
Codec ID                                 : 40
Duration                                 : 41mn 51s
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 56.0 Kbps
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Channel positions                        : Front: L R
Sampling rate                            : 22.05 KHz
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 16.8 MiB (21%)
Encoded date                             : UTC 1904-01-01 00:00:00
Tagged date                              : UTC 1904-01-01 00:00:00
```

It looks like the same info about `video B` that fail:

```
General
Complete name                            : openeya.mp4
Format                                   : MPEG-4
Format profile                           : Base Media
Codec ID                                 : isom
File size                                : 118 MiB
Duration                                 : 1h 16mn
Overall bit rate                         : 214 Kbps
Encoded date                             : UTC 1904-01-01 00:00:00
Tagged date                              : UTC 1904-01-01 00:00:00
Writing application                      : Lavf56.25.101
Video
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : High@L1.2
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
Format settings, ReFrames                : 4 frames
Codec ID                                 : avc1
Codec ID/Info                            : Advanced Video Coding
Duration                                 : 59mn 35s
Bit rate                                 : 200 Kbps
Width                                    : 320 pixels
Height                                   : 240 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 4:3
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 10.000 fps
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.260
Stream size                              : 85.2 MiB (72%)
Writing library                          : x264 core 142 r2389 956c8d8
Encoding settings                        : cabac=1 / ref=3 / deblock=1:0:0 / analyse=0x3:0x113 / me=hex / subme=7 / psy=1 / psy_rd=1.00:0.00 / mixed_ref=1 / me_range=16 / chroma_me=1 / trellis=1 / 8x8dct=1 / cqm=0 / deadzone=21,11 / fast_pskip=1 / chroma_qp_offset=-2 / threads=6 / lookahead_threads=1 / sliced_threads=0 / nr=0 / decimate=1 / interlaced=0 / bluray_compat=0 / constrained_intra=0 / bframes=3 / b_pyramid=2 / b_adapt=1 / b_bias=0 / direct=1 / weightb=1 / open_gop=0 / weightp=2 / keyint=250 / keyint_min=10 / scenecut=40 / intra_refresh=0 / rc_lookahead=40 / rc=abr / mbtree=1 / bitrate=200 / ratetol=1.0 / qcomp=0.60 / qpmin=0 / qpmax=69 / qpstep=4 / ip_ratio=1.40 / aq=1:1.00
Encoded date                             : UTC 1904-01-01 00:00:00
Tagged date                              : UTC 1904-01-01 00:00:00
Audio
ID                                       : 2
Format                                   : AAC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Audio Codec
Format profile                           : LC
Codec ID                                 : 40
Duration                                 : 1h 16mn
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 56.0 Kbps
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Channel positions                        : Front: L R
Sampling rate                            : 22.05 KHz
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 30.8 MiB (26%)
Encoded date                             : UTC 1904-01-01 00:00:00
Tagged date                              : UTC 1904-01-01 00:00:00
```

[Image with differencws](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2Ol7.png) Thanks @mt025

**So, why Youtube doesn't like `video B`?**

After the upload is finished YT keep processing and stop at 95% for ~5 minutes and after that

> The video has failed to process. Please make sure you are uploading a
>   supported file type.

Comment: You may have better luck at https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/youtube

Comment: It may be a bit easier to view the outputs differences, here: http://i.imgur.com/pDmgaEi.png

Comment: But that differences doesn't make sense to me. I was expecting "advanced" differences.

Comment: I didn't check out that image earlier. Encode with `-shortest`. Youtube probably doesn't like audio streams much longer than the video.

Comment: did not work. I've tried `ffmpeg -i file.mp4 -shortest - file2.mp4`, the streams stay different

Comment: @Mulvya, I had other priority, just now I could test. I cut the video to the shortest stream (using -ss and -t). And the output was uploaded with success. Is there a way to extend the video stream, to and static image? I can't lose the longer part of audio.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a bad block of data in the file, which prevents it from uploading. Try the following:

1) Re-encode. (This should probably work)

2) Try uploading elsewhere than YouTube

3) Try playing it through and confirm there are no errors.

4) Check your filesystem for errors.